# Failed to change ownership of the temporary files Ansible needs to create despite connecting as a privileged user

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx

I am new to awx i use pre-exsisting playbook when i run it from ubuntu 20 `terminal` it works fine but i want to run it through `awx` when i run it from awx i get this error.

> Failed to change ownership of the temporary files Ansible needs to create despite connecting as a privileged user. Unprivileged become user would be unable to read the file`

I install nextcloud from blog and i use these two commands at the end.

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/nextcloud
chmod -R 775 /var/www/html/nextcloud
```

the task where it throw error is this:

```
---
# tasks file for upgrade-nextcloud

- name: "[NC-Upgrade] - Get current version."
  become_user: "{{ nextcloud_websrv_user }}"
  command: php occ status --output=json
  args:
    chdir: "{{ nextcloud_webroot }}"
  register: nc_current_version
  changed_when: false
```

where `become_user: "{{ nextcloud_websrv_user }}"` is `www-data`. When i run it `become_user: root` then it say `/var/www/html/nextcloud` directory not found.

Do i need to mount the directory `/var/www/html/nextcloud` in `awx_web` container if i run it as a root.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue is fix the only problem is

```
connection:local
```

in `main.yml` so just need to remove it and i run it on a remote machine and also didn't provide the ssh credentials.